# Border around a form with rounded corner in c++ builder XE

Tags: border, c++builder, drag, rounding, c++builder-xe

I have made a C++ Builder XE form with rounded corner with the help of the following code

```
BorderStyle = bsNone; 

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
     HRGN frmrgn;  

     frmrgn = CreateRoundRectRgn (0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight,12,12);
     SetWindowRgn(Handle,frmrgn,true);
}
```

It looks cool but the border is missing, I tried many thing but not get good result 
so please help me to draw border of color RGB(96,96,96)

And I want to make whole form dragable.

Comment: I don't know, but `BorderStyle = bsNone;` sounds like you are asking for no border. What if you select some other style?

Comment: The answer to this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755719/rounded-and-titled-tpanel-in-delphi-7

Comment: @Bo Persson: The `BorderStyle` property only affects the standard Windows rectangular window border.  Since the window has curved corners the default border will be clipped and it will look weird - that's why @rudasgani needs to draw a custom border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Painting a dark grey border

This one's easy, depending on how complex you want the border to look.  If you just want an outline in dark grey, either draw it using a combination of lines and arcs, or use the [`FrameRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144839%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function to draw an outline around your region with a specific brush.  Doing this is the best solution since you already have a region you've used to define the shape of the window.

However, the MSDN documentation for [`SetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says, *"After a successful call to `SetWindowRgn`, the system owns the region specified by the region handle `hRgn`. The system does not make a copy of the region. Thus, you should not make any further function calls with this region handle."*  You'll need to create your region again for the paint method.

Some code for your paint method:

```
HRGN hRegion = ::CreateRoundRectRgn (0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight,12,12);
Canvas->Brush->Style = bsSolid;
Canvas->Brush->Color = RGB(96, 96, 96);
::FrameRgn(Canvas->Handle, hRegion, Canvas->Brush->Handle, 2, 2);
::DeleteObject(hRegion); // Don't leak a GDI object
```

### 2. Making the window draggable without its title bar

The short summary is that you need to handle the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.  Windows sends this to see if the mouse is over the title bar ('NC' stands for 'non-client'; it's actually testing to see if it's anywhere in the non-client area, which can be any window border, not just the top one.)  You can make your window draggable by saying 'yes, the mouse is in the caption right now' even when it isn't.  Some code:

```
// In the 'protected' section of your form's class declaration
virtual void __fastcall WndProc(Messages::TMessage &Message);

// The implementation of that method:
void __fastcall TForm1::WndProc(Messages::TMessage& Message) {
  TForm::WndProc(Message); // inherited implementation
  if (Message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && Msg.Result == htClient) {
    Msg.Result = htCaption;
  }
}
```

You can perform some hit testing of your own to restrict what parts of your window appear to be the title bar, in order to create a title bar of your own.

[Example Delphi code.](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/dragnocaption.htm)

[A good article about using this message, and things to be aware of / traps not to fall into.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/18/10131176.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very very very much brother your answer worth to me the first one is exact what i wanted but the other one is littlebit confusing i have to do some workout to understand it but bro thanks again please help me in future also

Comment: Thanks everyone to shaw your interest in my question Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  What is it you don't understand about the second?  If it's messages, here are some beginning links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows (about messages and the 'message loop' in general), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=VS.85%29.aspx (MSDN documentation) and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (the window procedure above - remember the VCL is object-oriented and is a wrapper around the low-level message loop / general structure of Windows.)

Comment: Thanks again bro that the message that i did not understand because i did not use it before in my program but links given by you are very useful Thanks

Comment: @rudasagani: If this answer was helpful (sounds like it!) could you mark it as the answer, please?  Click the checkmark / tick mark near the question's score.  On SO, this helps with people's reputation, both the answerer (me) and the questioner (you - you will get a percentage near your name of how many questions you mark as accepted, and if this is low people are unlikely to answer you.)