# How do I force a repaint of only the background so a control doesn't repaint over it again?

Tags: winapi, gdi

This question was generated by a response to another question: [Common Controls on a Transparent Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469342/).

Apparently, there is a way to only paint the background without a control painting itself again  This would solve the problem of having common control buttons on a transparent background.

So my question is, how do I paint only the background around a common control after the common control has painted itself?

Comment: I don't see anything in the post you linked (including the comments to it) or the answer that is posted there related to what you've stated here.

Comment: You mean, for example, to redraw a RoundRect button, and then you just need to redraw the redundant white border around the button.

Comment: yes.  How did someone get the description of the link to show up?

Comment: I don't know if my answer will help you. If it helps, please mark my answer.This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: does it work to fill all areas, say it was so rounded it was round, is it going to fill the entire square?   How about for transparent background, can you have an inverse invalidated path?

Comment: @user3161924 I think another way is to re-register a window class and customize the drawing of a button. You can control the drawing of the whole area, whether it's RounRect or transparent background area.

Answer (score 1):

About how to redraw visible borders.

The rounded rectangle drawn by `RoundRect` is used as representative

The [FrameRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-framergn) function draws a border around the specified region by using the specified brush.

Simple code demonstration：

```
HRGN hRegion = ::CreateRoundRectRgn (0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight,12,12);
Canvas->Brush->Style = bsSolid;
Canvas->Brush->Color = RGB(96, 96, 96);
::FrameRgn(Canvas->Handle, hRegion, Canvas->Brush->Handle, 2, 2);
::DeleteObject(hRegion); // Don't leak a GDI object
```

Link you need: [Redraw Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174134/border-around-a-form-with-rounded-corner-in-c-builder-xe)